# How to setup MySQL database for demo version?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5.1

My Laravel project uses MySQL. I want to host my project's demo version where anyone can login using the given credentials and perform any operation he is permitted to with his role. When he logs out the changes he made should be gone. And at the same time multiple users with same credentials can manipulate data which should be isolated without making changing to other's current database. How can I achieve this ?

Comment: What kind of changes would they be making? If they are changes to values in a database, then when they log out you could truncate the tables and simply re-seed them.

Comment: The problem is if i truncate the database then others users logged in at the same time would see inconsistency right ?

Comment: Yes they would. But unless you set up an environment for each individual user as they arrive then there would be inconsistencies anyway. (e.g if I delete a user it would disappear for you too despite you not deleting them)

Answer (score 0):

You could write a SQL file which contains all of the SQL commands necessary to "reset" the database. This could be, for example, deleting all records and pre-populating tables with the "default" records. You could then fire this script each time the user logs off.

It sounds like it would be difficult and time consuming to write a script like this, but most SQL clients can generate this for you when you "backup" the database to SQL file (when you backup to SQL file, it simply writes all the SQL commands necessary to restore the database).

I hope this helps.

Comment: For example the demo projects in CodeCanyon, multiple users can log into the demo version and perform some actions with default records at the same time. Suppose a user logs in makes changes, logs out then the script to reset the database is executed. But at the same time other users are logged in. As I reset the only version of the database then what will those users see ?

Comment: Yes - but by this logic, users will be able to see the changes the other users are making anyway. How are you preventing this?

Comment: You could create a whole database each time a user logs on, then run the script to delete the database when they log off. This would also mean that the users can't see what other users are doing. This would be achieved by a similar script (to create the DB) and then a script at the end to drop the DB.

Comment: So u are suggesting that I should try to delete the database while other users are logged in ?

Comment: No. Each user would be accessing their own database.

Answer (score 0):

If I had to do this, I would use Docker (a simple way of accessing linux containers).

I would look at providing the whole stack of the target environment in a container, then providing a proxy on a random URL:
* .host.domain/
* host.domain//
* host.domain:/

A copy of your application environment would be spawned inside a container, configured to expose it's internal port 80/443 as some other number, then you would provide a way for the user to connect by creating a virtual host/directory that proxies this.

This way, your application does not need to deal with any weird database row/table/port/name changes internally -it just needs to cope with being run behind different URLs.

I have built something like this behind nginx (which allows me to load and unload proxies without affecting existing sessions), to deliver application environments that would otherwise suffer from user data collisions - see http://docker.stat.auckland.ac.nz/

In this example, when a user requests an instance, the application directory is mounted read only inside a docker instance at /srv/shiny/, and port 3838 in the container is mapped to some 7999 <  < 10000 on the host.

I then create the following from a template, placing it in a folder configured to be read by my nginx server:

```
location /<random instance name>/
{
    proxy_pass http://localhost:<port>;
    proxy_redirect http://localhost:<port>/ $scheme://$server_name/;
}
```

and run a 'systemctl reload nginx' to get the new instance up, handing the uri back to the user.